# powering multiple servos from 12v controlled by arduino

Tags: arduino, servo

I am trying to control 8 servo's with an `arduino uno` using `ROS`.
The diagram below shows my current configuration to power the servos.  I have a buck regulator in between the 12v battery and the breadboard.

The arduino is powered thru a barrel plug which goes into a 12v regulator which connects to the 12v battery.

This does not seem to work when I have many servos. Strange things happen when I try to manipulate all 8 servos at once, a few respond but most do not.  Also they all seem to get jitters and wobble while plugged in.

Why is that?  Also what is the best way to power up and use many servos? 
I planned on using the `arduino mega 2560` to manipulate up to 30 servos.
[image]
buck 5v:

> Module Properties: Non-isolated step-down module (buck). 
>   Rectifier: Non-Synchronous Rectification. 
>   Wide Input voltage: DC 4.5-40V. 
>   Output Voltage: DC 1.2-37V (Adjustable) (output voltage from the USB = output voltage from the output port ).  
>   Output current: rated current 2A, 3A MAX (Additional heatsink is required). 
>   If you need its output power greater than 2A/10W, please add with heat-sink. 
>   Short circuit protection: current limiting, since the recovery. 
>   Operating temperature: Industrial grade (-40 to +85 ) 
>   Load regulation:±0.5% 
>   Voltage regulation:± 2.5% 
>   No CC, current display function

each servo:
[image]

Comment: More than likely the 5V buck can't provide enough current. We can't answer this without specifications for the servos and buck converter. Please **edit the question** and include the details.

Comment: @transistor thank you,  please let me know if the revised question is sufficient.

Comment: Excellent. We're missing one piece of information - the stall or start current for the motor. Can you measure either the motor resistance (which we will use with Ohm's law to work out the max current) or measure the current drawn by one servo while you stall it during a commanded move. If we can work out the worst case current drawn be one servo we can see how many you could simultaneously move with your PSU.

Comment: @transistor what would be the best way for me to measure this?  I am unsure how to go about this task.

Comment: @transistor rather than having all servos powered by a single buck regulator, should I have multiple regulators for groups of 2 or 3 servos?

Comment: Let's use a chat room or the site will complain about conversations in comments. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33416/jittery-arduino-servos

Comment: Does your real life setup resemble the one with the breadboard in the picture? If so move the power supply leads closer to the servo's connections.

Comment: @jippie I see, have all connections closer together?

Comment: Sometimes the power rails along the sides are interrupted (by design) somewhere half way.

Comment: Consider using multiple regulators each handling a smaller number of servos.  Also consider "battery eliminator" circuits (again, probably several) intended for use in model craft powered by 3 lithium polymer batteries, as such a pack has comparable voltage range to your input.  Ideally group servos that won't move together (at least with high load) on the same regulator, and servos that will move together on different regulators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information we have so far it appears that your buck converter may not be able to supply enough current to run all the servos simultaneously.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUBPsa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your general layout is good in that you have kept the power wiring separate from the motor wiring where the high currents could cause problems (such as burning out the PCB tracks or causing interference) if they ran back to the battery via the Arduino. The layout is poor because your are using the breadboard to carry relatively high currents. You should come up with a better way of connecting these.

The 12 V regulator between the battery and the Arduino isn't doing much. 12 V in, 12 V out. If anything I would reduce the output of this to, say, 8 V so there will be less heat dissipated in the Arduino voltage regulator.

Further updates as info comes in via chat room.

[Update]

From discussion in the chat rooms it appears to be a supply current problem. The buck converter hasn't enough oomph to power more than three or four servos under load.

Comment: I should remove the breadboard from the loop?

Comment: You're only using it as a terminal strip. Fine for tens of mA but not so good for hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't current limiting causing the servos problems then it's the horrible 0V scheme you've adopted. Try connecting the arduino's supply directly to the servos power feed because, at the moment, you have a very strong possibility of 0V bounce corrupting the control lines fed to those servos. Keep all wires as short as possible.

I see you cannot use the local supply to the servo so just reconnect the 0V as I've hinted.

Comment: I made an update to my wiring diagram,  the arduino is powered by a barrel and regulator

Comment: You should have a direct connection between the arduino ground and the servo ground.

Comment: Why have you updated the wiring diagram?

Comment: @Andyaka because originally it looked like I was powering from the usb, also I forgot to mention a regulator inbetween the arduino and 12v

Comment: @PeterBennett are you saying that there should be a ground connection from each servo to the arduino?

Comment: @PeterBennett: I think he should avoid ground loops and star all the commons out from the battery as he has shown in his schematic. This will be best practice and avoid high currents flowing in the control circuitry ground wires / plane.